# Getting email to work on openshift ruby application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, openshift, email

I can't seem to get email for password recovery using devise to work on my openshift app. I'm using Rails 4.0.2 and Ruby 1.9.3. I've tried the following in `production.rb` :

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => 25,
  :address        => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
  :user_name      => 'postmaster@domain.com',
  :password       => '[password]',
  :domain         => 'mydomain.com.mailgun.domain',
  :authentication => :plain,
}
```

I've also done settings required for google use and both worked fine in development on local. Also tried ports 465, 587, as [described here](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/outbound-mail-ports-are-now-open-for-business-on-openshift). Sending mail unfortunately still isn't performed on production. The app just throws an error with nothing in the logs.

Comment: One option would be to use the mailgun api with openshift as described [here](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/email-in-the-cloud-with-mailgun).

Comment: What is the error message that it throws?